# Making a dynamic grid with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm trying to create a dynamic grid using jquery where it will eventually change with user input (i.e. 16x16, 32x32, etc). My logic is to create 16 rows and then 16 squares within each row, but I'm having trouble getting the squares to append the correct amount.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
        $('.grid').append("<div class = 'row'></div>");
      //$('.row').width(($('.square').width().val() * i);
      //for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
           $('.row').append("<div class='square'></div>");
    // }
    }
});
```

Here is a link to what it looks like: https://lettda.github.io/EtchAsketch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your inner for loop outside of the outer for loop should create the proper amount of squares, as such:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    $('.grid').append("<div class = 'row'></div>"); // Each grid gets 16 rows
}

for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    $('.row').append("<div class='square'></div>"); // Each row gets 16 squares
}
```

Explicitly setting the width of the row is not necessary, as it will automatically be 16 times the width of your square plus any padding/margin you add. Note that all your squares would need `display: inline-block;` in the CSS to ensure that they are side by side. Also, the rows would wrap if there are too many squares in each row or the squares are too wide.

Answer (score 0):

`.row` selects all the elements which have the class `row` which means that you're not appending the `.square` `div`s to only the last created row, you're appending them to all the previously created ones as well.

To prevent that, you can do something like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
    var row = $("<div class = 'row'></div>");
    for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) { 
        var square = $("<div class='square'></div>");
        row.append(square);
    }
    $('.grid').append(row);
}
```

OR

```
for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) { 
  $('.grid').append("<div class='row' id='row"+i+"'></div>");
  for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) { 
      $('#row'+i).append("<div class='square'></div>");
  }
}
```